# Magento 2 how to make group attribute in customer info multiselect?

Tags: magento2, group, multiple, multiselect

How to make it to allow customers belonging to multiple groups? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is pretty straightforward turns a select attribute into multi-select (You just need update some parameters). But is extremely complicated to refactor all business logic around that specific attribute which include:

1. Customer Base Logic/Validation
2. Price Rules
3. Sales Rules
4. Index behaviour
5. Taxes

And so on... my point is that make this kind of changes require a serious  research about the real impact.

I'm pretty sure that isn't a question able to be answered in a few lines. IMO

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried to change the frontend_input from select to multiselect, it is work for Product attribute, but not work for Goup

Comment: I think that only change the attribute frontend_input is a very bad idea.

Comment: I've done customization on the business rely on it, I just want to let admin manage the groups a customer belongs to. Thanks